# Oracle 19.3.0.0.0 Password authentication failed

Tags: oracle, security, connect, oracle19c

I made a PDB and I can connect to this PDB by sys as sysdba, but I can't connect my own common or just local users.

The reason is ORA-01017: bad password.

After I set in sqlnet.ora:

```
SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_SERVER=11
```

And the password starts end ends with quation mark, then works.

Commands to create user and login user:

```
create user c##test identified by "test" container=all;
grant create session to c##test container=all;
alter pluggable database FTR_SHOWCASE open;
conn c##test/"test"@localhost:1521/FTR_SHOWCASE
```

Why? How can I upgrade SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_SERVER to 12.
Can I password set without quotion mark?

Can it be encoding problem?

Thanks.

H.

Comment: what is your connection string to connect to the database ?

Comment: sqlplus sys@localhost:1521/ftr_showcase as sysdba   Soo good!   sqlplus other_user@localhost:1521/ftr_showcase    not good

Comment: is it possible you created your other_user in a db other than ftr_showcase, like ORCLPDB1 ?

Answer (score 1):

WHEN using EZCONNECT to connect to the database you need to provide a password for the user:

```
sqlplus user/pwd@hostname:port/service_name
```

or you need to declare an alias to your pdb in your tnsnames.ora and connect using:

```
sqlplus user@alias
```

In your first exemple it works because oracle use the os authentication to connect you.

**TEST:**

```
SQL> create pluggable database FTR_SHOWCASE from PDBINV;

Pluggable database created.

SQL> create user c##test identified by "test" container=all;

User created.

SQL> grant create session to c##test container=all;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> alter pluggable database FTR_SHOWCASE open;

Pluggable database altered.

SQL> conn c##test/"test"@localhost:1521/FTR_SHOWCASE
Connected.
```

It's worked after a db change.

A must set SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_SERVER=11 in sqlnet.ora  Then it works!
But why isn't good by default value?

And very weird, but "test" is good with quotation marks. Password without quot is 10170 bad password.

Comment: After the command i type the pasword by sys too. And it doesn't work by connect command too.

Comment: did you try : sqlplus user/pwd@hostname:port/service_name ?

Comment: Yes, but said bad password... Create session privilege is enough?

Comment: it doesn't make sense, do the following:
sqlplus / as sysdba
create user c##test identified by "test";
grant create session to c##test container=all;

then 

show pdbs
conn c##test/test@localhost:1521/ftr_showcase

Comment: Sys user can connect without password... Like postgresql ident? Like dont works password check!!!

Comment: show what you did because I can't help you if you don't give any details

Comment: sqlplus sys as sysdba/@localhost:1521/ftr_showcase   without pass just enter twice

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203778/discussion-between-cyrille-modiano-and-laszlo-toth).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203789/discussion-between-cyrille-modiano-and-laszlo-toth).